# Storing huge amount of records in a mysql table...is it normal?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I have developed a small system based on PHP and Mysql.
Its  more like a teacher create notes using a WYSIWYG editor and share among the students.

For teachers I have done some analysis. One of them is how long they spent on each course and on which date. Using a jquery to detect the browser activities adding records to a table.

Say subject Mathematics and it has 3 chapters. I will accumulate the time spent on each chapter and group by date and display.

if the student idle for 15 mins I stop counting and add a record
if the student go to another tab, then stop counting and add a record,
if the student click another link I add another record.
close the browser also same. 
if they are going to another chapter, then again I add another record and start counting in the next chapter.
And finally accumulate the time spent.

Now, I am using it my college and i can see within 2 months, around 10,000 records has been added.

I am using the primary key as Int(10), auto Increment.

is it a good programming. Any alternatives.

[This is how the analysis shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obCro.png)

[This the table stores records...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jycLp.png)

**Sorry for the LONG POST**

Comment: 10000 records is not a huge amount of records. If you're worried about the fact that your auto increment will run out of numbers. It would take millenniums if every 2 months 10k records will be added.

Comment: 10k records in 2 month is not even close to `HUGE` amount of records

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: 10.000 records is peanuts, for performance, make sure you have indexes on your foreign keys.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I disagree, a comment would have been that we can not assess if the programming is good, without seeing the actual code.